# "No subscriptions found for Azure Account"

Tags: azure

In Azure trial subscription my MSN email is associated with an other account with owner rights. But when I try to access [Azure publishSettings](https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/) it generates an error [No Subscription fouund](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SGGC.png) .

Please help me to resolve the issue. Do I need Co-administrator or Service Administrator rights along with owner rights ?

Comment: Have you tried the Service Admin or Co-Admin as suggested below? If so and it works, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Service Administrator and Co-Administrator originated with the old portal at http://manage.windowsazure.com. The new portal, found at http://portal.azure.com, has introduced role based access control (RBAC), which provides the notion of Owner. You can find a lot of details about RBAC at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/.

When RBAC was rolled out, Administrators where automatically added as Owners. It's possible to be an RBAC Owner in a subscription without being an Administrator, as Owner applies to ResourceGroups or Resources within a subscription.

The webpage you're trying to use has been available for a long time and from the looks of it has not have been updated to support RBAC. The download of the publish profile from that webpage is based on selecting a subscription, which an Owner of a ResourceGroup or Resource would not necessarily have full access to everything in the subscription.

That means if you have your account added as a Co-Administrator or Service Administrator, that webpage should work.

Comment: My user is in the global admin role and still has no access to the classic portal. Any other ideas?

Comment: Global Admin is not the same as Service Administrator or Co-Administrator. I believe Global Admin applies to Azure Active Directory and Office 365, not Azure.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the difference between Microsoft Account and Azure Active Directory Account. Check which you are using.

I suggest you to clear all cookies, cache and temporary internet files on browser or use **InPrivate/Incognito** mode. Login again and it will work.

Comment: Going in with Private browsing session worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Sign Out" button and then login with the account that is associated with your trial.  Owner rights should be sufficient.

Comment: You could try a private/incognito window.  Signing out and logging in with the right creds fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found an answer but in searching for an answer I found this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/#how-to-change-service-administrator-for-a-subscription) which says the owners you added through the Azure portal cannot manage services in the Azure classic portal.

So I MUST add co-administrator IN  the classic portal so they can administer classic portal

Worked immediately after added my New Portal global admin as a co-administrator in the classic portal

nigel.jones@kloud.com.au

Comment: If you get licenses through CSP you don't get access to the old portal. This is frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

My company uses Azure DevOps but when I login I don't see any subscriptions.

```
az login
No subscriptions found for xyz@xyz.com.
```

When I go to https://portal.azure.com and go to subscriptions it shows this message:

```
Your current access does not include permissions to view any
subscriptions.
```

### Solution:

I just login without subscription and everyhing still works.

`az login --allow-no-subscriptions`