# Azure Functions in VS Code Plugin doesn't find subscriptions

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm developing an azure function in VS Code. I have the Azure Functions extension installed.

I have created the function and its running locally just fine.

But when I sign in to azure using the extension it does not see any of my Azure subscriptions. Therefore I can't select a subscription and deploy the function.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a workaround?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I was able to sign in by clearing the azure tenant id in the azure extension settings for VS Code

Comment: The extension is called 'Azure Account' now. In the extension setting, the 'Azure: Tenant' in the form of a GUID should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Move your mouse to there, you will see a filter icon.
Click it, then you will find all subscriptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to the following ways to troubleshoot.

1.Go to azure portal and login your account to check if the account has active subscription listed.

2.In VS code, try to sign out and sign in again.

3.Use the below script with azure cli to login your account

```
az login --debug
```

4.If you have set MFA for your account, re-open the browser and re-login to the portal, which triggered the wizard for me to configure all needed for MFA authentication. After that, `az login` works again.

Comment: I've tried all of these and still no luck. The extension continually prompts 'No subscriptions were found. Set up your account at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/.'

Comment: You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149380/no-subscriptions-found-for-azure-account) for further troubleshoot.